# Replace nan's for a list according to another list with different sizes python

Tags: python, numpy, nan, data-cleaning

I would like to replace nan's in a list with values from a second list which has exactly same number of elements as the number of nan's in the first list.

```
mylist1 = list([1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 5])

mylist2 = list([-10, -11, -12])
```

What I want is:

```
mylist1 = [1, 2, 3, -10, -11, 4, -12, 5]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already using numpy (`np.nan` in there) you should use ndarrays, not lists.  But you can convert back if you want:

```
>>> a = np.array(mylist1)
>>> a[np.isnan(a)] = mylist2
>>> a.astype(int).tolist()
[1, 2, 3, -10, -11, 4, -12, 5]
```